# Mono.zip request fails when subscribed

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

I have the following piece of code, where externalgetcall is a GET request to a external service asking for some data

```
myservice.externalgetcall(id).blockOptional();
```

this code works, but if i get rid of the blockOptional and write the following, externalgetcall fails with a java.lang.NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.saveAuthorizedClient(HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.java:63) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
> Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
> Error has been observed at the following site(s):
> *__checkpoint ? Request to GET

```
myservice.externalgetcall(id).subscribe();
```

moreover, if I do this, the blocking one right before the non blocking one, it works, so it clearly has to do with Oauth not completing somehow if the call is non blocking:

```
myservice.externalgetcall(id).blockOptional();
myservice.externalgetcall(id).subscribe();
```

**externalgetcall(id)**

```
public Mono<MyClass> externalgetcall(String id) {
    logger.debug("getting contact: {}", id);
    return this.webClient
            .get()
            .uri(externaluri)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(MyClass.class)
            .doOnNext(myClass -> logger.debug("success {}", myClass))
            .doOnError(throwable -> logger.error("error : ", throwable))
            
}
```

**it fails at this point:**
it looks like it happens when trying to run the setAttribute method,when debugging i can see this:

> this = {FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription@13199}  size = 1
> Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception.

```
public final class HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository implements OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository {
private static final String DEFAULT_AUTHORIZED_CLIENTS_ATTR_NAME = HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.class.getName() + ".AUTHORIZED_CLIENTS";
private final String sessionAttributeName;

public HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository() {
    this.sessionAttributeName = DEFAULT_AUTHORIZED_CLIENTS_ATTR_NAME;
}

public void saveAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient, Authentication principal, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (this.isPrincipalAuthenticated(principal)) {
            this.authorizedClientService.saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient, principal);
        } else {
            this.anonymousAuthorizedClientRepository.saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient, principal, request, response);
        }

    }

public void saveAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient, Authentication principal, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Assert.notNull(authorizedClient, "authorizedClient cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(response, "response cannot be null");
    Map<String, OAuth2AuthorizedClient> authorizedClients = this.getAuthorizedClients(request);
    authorizedClients.put(authorizedClient.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), authorizedClient);
    request.getSession().setAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName, authorizedClients);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not much context to come to a rock-solid explanation, but the NPE leads me to believe that this is a case of race condition.

Something to consider is the fact that you are replacing a blocking terminal operation with an asynchronous terminal operation on the publisher. `blockOptional` and `subscribe` both initiate a subscription, but in the latter case, execution will not wait at that point for the publisher's onComplete signal.

Again, hard to tell without the complete code, but my guess is that whatever code comes **after** this snippet is using some data that is populated or hydrated as a result of this publisher. Using `blockOptional` ensures that the publisher completes before this happens, while `subscribe` does not.

Comment: Hi, i think you may be right, I tried the same with another external service and it worked. So i guess something is interfering here and it looks like it is something from the Oauth configuration. Im gonna update the main thread with more info.

Comment: @Battalgazi It would be useful to also know what `myservice::externalgetcall` and `anotherservice::dosomething` do. The `saveAuthorizedClient` method contents are a good start, but before I can give a detailed answer, I need to know more. Also preferably some info about the methods called in `saveAuthorizedClient`.

Comment: I updated again the description with simplified codes and example, plus the functions related.

Comment: @Battalgazi Are you just using a WebClient with a servlet stack, or is your entire stack reactive?

Comment: @Battalgazi If your whole stack is reactive, then therein lies your problem. `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` is meant only for servlet usage, as apparent from its methods that receive `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects. You need to rethink your OAuth strategy; the reactive equivalent of this class is `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`.

Comment: No, it is WebClient with a servlet stack

Comment: @Battalgazi Since your stack is servlet, there is nothing wrong with blocking. You can of course use the Reactor publishers to your liking, but at some point, you will have to block. The underlying servlet container will still assign 1 thread per request, so there is nothing to be gained by trying to make it work as non-blocking. If you're adamant, double check your web client configuration against docs, e.g. [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/servlet-webclient.html)